# Appending multiple items to a default parameter with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse with Python 2.7.x and am having some trouble appending to a default parameter list. The pertinent code is shown below:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(...)

parser.add_argument('--project-list', action='append', dest='project_list',
                    nargs='*', default=['AAA', 'BBB'])

# ...

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.project_list
```

Which prints the following when called:

```
$ python program.py --project-list CCC # --> project_list=['AAA', 'BBB', ['CCC']]

$ python program.py --project-list CCC DDD # --> project_list=['AAA', 'BBB', ['CCC', 'DDD']]
```

**However, what I would like the program to do is illustrated below**:

```
$ python program.py --project-list CCC  # --> project_list=['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']

$ python program.py --project-list CCC DDD  # --> project_list=['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

From what I've found so far it seems the `nargs` parameter forces a list to be made, which is then appended (not sure why?).

A few other solutions such as passing `type=str`, or `type=construct_project_list` (which is a function that returns a 'valid' list) haven't worked either...

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: I'm confused by `--projects`. Was that intended to be `--project-list`? Or is `--projects` an argument that you define elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry, yea `--projects` shoulda been `--project-list`. I've updated it.

Comment: With the default 'store' Action, and `nargs` being '*',"+' or a number, the value is a list.   With `append`, that same list is appended to `[]` or the default.  Try, for example, `--proj CCC DDD --proj AAA --proj BBB`.  So what you see is a simple consequence of appending lists.  No special code.  But look at the `_AppendAction` class if you want to understand the behavior better.

Comment: If you set `default=[['AAA', 'BBB']]`, then the nesting will be consistent, `[['AAA', 'BBB'], ['CCC', 'DDD'], ['KKK'], etc]`.